# Simple way to install Ruby with gems on a customer site

Tags: ruby, installation, environment, runtime

What's the simplest way -- ideally a single click -- to set up a ruby (not rails) runtime environment on a local Windows system (not a web site), with specific gems?

I have code for a customer that runs on their local system.  I've been sending them ocra executables, and that sorta, kinda, usually works, but is showing more problems all the time.

So I want to set up a native ruby environment there -- actually I want them to set it up -- so I can just send straight ruby code. But it's got to have the specific gems I use (FxRuby, several others).

Most important, it's gotta be dead simple for them -- ideally a single click.   I'm trying to avoid a physical trip to their site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As they are running Windows why not go to the ruby-lang.org website and download the windows installer - depending on the edition they do come with gems - some with FXRuby (which I use myself) you can then send the app to them and they can install Ruby - It is quiite simple to do.

Comment: Are you sure? FxRuby is highly non-standard -- not even supported anymore (!*@#! bad choice on my part, I guess). Plus I have other non-standard gems that I had to install myself by hand. I doubt that they are in either of the two one-click installers (one for ruby, one for rails).

Comment: Why is it so hard to use the "standard" one-click installer and then instruct them to "gem install fxruby"?

Answer (score 0):

In the ruby code before you make it an ocra file put

```
`gem install mygem`
`gem install myothergem`
```

in backsticks...

This will run in the command line of the receiving computer. Then require the gems later in your script.

Let me know if this works.